# How does a flap load relief system work?

Tags: flaps

I recently read about flap load relief systems in some aircraft that attempt to prevent flap overspeeds by automatically retracting flaps under certain conditions.

- Are these systems common on all large aircraft or are they specific to just a few?
- How do they work (i.e. under what conditions will they retract flaps)?
- Do they prevent the possibility of overspeeding flaps altogether, or do they just make it less likely to happen?

Comment: To the best of my remembrance there was no flap load relief system on 747-100s and -200s. Also, I can't find any reference to such in the documentation I still have.

Comment: Nor is there such a system on the ERJ-170/190 (to add a currently produced transport category aircraft to this discussion).

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure how common flap load relief systems are - I know the Airbus A330 has them and I believe all the Airbus A3xx series do. I've also found [at least one post that seems to imply it's common on most "large commercial" aircraft](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/tech_ops/read.main/340657/), which I assume encompasses most transport category aircraft.

On the Airbus the system is based on airspeed - When the maximum flap extension speed (V<sub>FE</sub>) is exceeded by a certain threshold the ship's computer automatically retracts the flaps.
My understanding is the retraction is staged, so if you've got full flaps selected and exceed V<sub>FE</sub> for that flap setting the system takes out one notch -- presumably it would continue doing so if you're still exceeding the operating limitations of the flap system until it reaches a point where it's convinced you're not going to damage the airframe.

When the overspeed condition is corrected (the speed has reduced to below V<sub>fe</sub> by a set threshold) the flaps are returned to the selected position.

Answer (score 7):

To add on to this old question, here's the load relief schedule for a 777-200ER.

[image]